# How to Create a new language model NLP? - Python

Tags: python, nlp, voice-recognition, transcription

i use Google Api to transcript some audio files to text with Recognizer class. I found out there are limited numbers of languages available, and the most commonly and internationally used are part of it.
How can i
Create a new language out of vocabulary & Train it, to then
Use the language as a recognizer for audio input

Use it as language as in en-US: `

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

r.recognize_google(language="en-US",audio_text)`
```

Note: I have made several searches but doesn't seem to get the exact answer to what i need... I'm on Python

Thank you

Comment: `Gensim` library has provided you with an easy and intuitive API to implement different types of language models on your desired corpus. I have done it several times but I have no idea about how you can utilize it for the speech recognition tasks.

Comment: @meti Thank you, that sets me already on good track

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how to train a ML model to do Automatic Speech Recognition on a specific language ?", you will first need a corpus with speech and their respective transcripts. Then, you can use for example Speechbrain to teach the model with the corpus.
If you just want to use an ASR for your specific language, do not forget to check if the model already exists.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly my query.... will check that out and come if anything
Have some references on corpus making?

Comment: Creating a corpus for ASR is not a easy task, require too much time for one person I think. Here is a paper talking about efficient ways to create one. I would recommend you to find an already existing corpus.